# Regex match groups lookback

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds, fluentd, fastly

I'm trying to extract the same data (but in different "chunks" from a string several times. The use-case is parsing of Syslog messages from Fastly in Fluentd.

I have this log line:

`2015-08-27T12:36:58Z cache-foo1234 Name[123456]: 4.151.22.16 "-" "-" POST /api/v1/foo/61ea23fb-53fb-4364-a892-349fdf5f6dca/event?release_type=store&version=2%2E0%2E1&os=ios&device_os_version=8%2E4&device_type=iphone 304 MISS BC942858-64FA-4101-BAE1-19272490697F iPhone 5S`

and this regex (Ruby Regex) so far:

`^(?<time>[^ ]*) (?<fastly_server>[^ ]*) (?<log_name>[^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<na>[^ ]*) (?<na2>[^ ]*) (?<http_method>[^ ]*) (?<http_request>[^ ]*) (?<http_status>[^ ]*) (?<cache_status>[^ ]*) (?<uuid>[^ ]*) *(?<device_model>.*)$`

and this gives me:

- `time` 2015-08-27T12:36:58Z
- `fastly_server`   cache-foo1234
- `log_name`    Name[123456]:
- `host`    4.151.22.16
- `http_method` POST
- `http_request`    /api/v1/foo/61ea23fb-53fb-4364-a892-349fdf5f6dca/event?release_type=store&version=2%2E0%2E1&os=ios&device_os_version=8%2E4&device_type=iphone
- `http_status` 304
- `cache_status`    MISS
- `uuid`    BC942858-64FA-4101-BAE1-19272490697F
- `device_model`    iPhone 5S

and that is perfect, but how can I go back and extract ie. `61ea23fb-53fb-4364-a892-349fdf5f6dca`, `event` and the value of `device_os_version` from the same string with the same regex?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated regex:

```
^(?<time>[^ ]*) (?<fastly_server>[^ ]*) (?<log_name>[^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<na>[^ ]*) (?<na2>[^ ]*) (?<http_method>[^ ]*) (?<http_request>\/api\/v\d+\/foo\/(?<guid>[^\/]+)\/(?<event>[^\/?]+)[^ ]*device_os_version=(?<devosver>[^=&]+)[^ ]*) (?<http_status>[^ ]*) (?<cache_status>[^ ]*) (?<uuid>[^ ]*) *(?<device_model>.*)$
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/WNVBpYzGmd)

I just replaced your `(?<http_request>)` part to

```
(?<http_request>\/api\/v\d+\/foo\/(?<guid>[^\/]+)\/(?<event>[^\/?]+)[^ ]*device_os_version=(?<devosver>[^=&]+)[^ ]*)
                ^----------------^^-----GUID-------^^--event-------^     ^-------OS Version--------   -------^
```